# How to use std::wstring with std::istringstream?

Tags: c++, stl, stream

I am trying to write a template function which will extract the value of the given datatype from the given string. I came up with something like this:

```
   template<class T>
    static T getValue(const CString& val_in)
    {
        std::wstring value = val_in;
        std::istringstream iss;
        iss.str(value);

        T val = T();
        iss>>val;
        return val;
    }
```

But this gives the following error for the `iss.str(value)` statement.

> error C2664: 'void
>   std::basic_istringstream<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::str(const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>
>   &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'std::wstring' to 'const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>
>   &'

So basically, `std::istringstream` is accepting only `std::string` . I thought there may be a `std::wistringstream` but there doesn't seem to be one available. Any clues how can I do it?

Comment: What makes you think that there isn't a `wistringstream` available? See 27.7 [lib.string.streams].

Comment: @Charles, I got a compiler error (on VC9) when I tried wistringstream, let me try that again.

Comment: Oops..compiling now, not sure what I changed other than this..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My compiler has wistringstream -- this is all it is:

`typedef basic_istringstream<wchar_t> wistringstream;`

Comment: yes, it is there..I think there was an error somewhere else and I got confused.